# Confused about Windows 8.1 MSDN update

Tags: windows-8, msdn, windows-8.1-upgrade

I've just installed Windows 8 from an MSDN ISO, activated with a DreamSpark key, and updated. Now the store shows the free update to Windows 8.1, but as far as I know, it shouldn't be available for MSDN Win8 installs.
Does anyone know whether I'm safe to try to run the 8.1 installer? Will it work with my activation code? I don't want to mess it up, it's a one-time activation.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an ISO on MSDN that will allow you to update. I wouldn't advise updating using the store. See [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store) for details.

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft specifically says that MSDN installs should not be able to update to 8.1 via the Store. While it's there, it's usually better to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Ramhound In the article I linked: "Editions of Windows 8 that are installed using an MSDN ISO, and activated using multiple activation keys"

Comment: I didn't see the bottom half of that support article.  You are indeed correct.  Although a Dreamspark license can't be activated on multiple computers(or isn't suppose to) and isn't considered a MSDN license .  I maintain that if the update is in the Windows Store he should use that method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are safe because the Dreamspark keys are retail keys. Only when you used MAK Keys or KMS activation the 8.1 Update is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The Dreamspark install of windows 8 will definitely let you update through the store, as if it was a retail version - my system runs one of those, and it updated without a hitch. I do believe that your system should have asked you if you wanted to update by now.